# Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation with binary heaps

Tags: java, heap, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree, min-heap

I've been trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm with binary heaps for my algorithms class.The goal is to find the length of the minimum spanning tree found through Dijkstra. I've worked with before, but using Priority queues. I find I'm getting tripped up with the heap management, and if anyone could spot errors. Main method is below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File input = new File("filepath\1000.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

            //Regex patterns used to find input size, nodes, and edges
            String size = "n=([0-9]*)";
            String node = "^[0-9]+";
            String edge = "^[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)";

            Pattern sizePattern = Pattern.compile(size);
            Pattern edgePattern = Pattern.compile(edge);
            Pattern nodePattern = Pattern.compile(node);


            //Loop to fill nodeList
            ArrayList <Integer> finalDistances = new ArrayList<>();
            MinHeap list = null;
            Node currentNode = null;
            Edge currentEdge = null;
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher match1 = sizePattern.matcher(line);
                Matcher match2 = nodePattern.matcher(line);
                Matcher match3 = edgePattern.matcher(line);
                //catches size
                if(match1.find()) {
                    int numberOfNodes = Integer.parseInt(match1.group(1));
                    //Holds all the nodes to process with Dijkstra's Algo
                    list = new MinHeap(numberOfNodes);
                }
                //catches node
                if (match2.find()) {
                    if (!list.contains(Integer.parseInt(line))) {
                        currentNode = new Node(Integer.parseInt(line));
                        currentNode.seen = false;
                        currentNode.distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        list.insert(currentNode);
                    }
                    else {
                        currentNode = list.getNode(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    }
                }
                //catches edge
                if(match3.find()) {
                    if (!list.contains(Integer.parseInt(match3.group(1)))) {
                        Node temp = new Node(Integer.parseInt(match3.group(1)));
                        temp.seen = false;
                        temp.distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                        list.insert(temp);
                        currentEdge = new Edge(Integer.parseInt(match3.group(1)), Integer.parseInt(match3.group(2)));
                        currentNode.add(currentEdge);
                    } else {
                        currentEdge = new Edge(Integer.parseInt(match3.group(1)), Integer.parseInt(match3.group(2)));
                        currentNode.add(currentEdge);
                    }
                }
            }
            Node source = list.getNode(0);
            source.distance=0;
            list.updateNode(source);
            int treeLength = 0;
            while(!list.isEmpty()) {
                currentNode = list.extractMin();
                currentNode.seen = true;
                ArrayList<Edge> edgeList = currentNode.edges;
                for (int i = 0; i < edgeList.size(); i++) {
                    currentEdge = edgeList.get(i);
                    if (list.contains(currentEdge.end)) {
                        int calcDist = currentNode.distance + currentEdge.weight;
                        if (calcDist < list.getNode(currentEdge.end).distance) {
                            list.decreaseKey(list.getNode(currentEdge.end), calcDist);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(currentNode.toString() + "with distance" +currentNode.distance);
                finalDistances.add(currentNode.distance);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < finalDistances.size(); j++) treeLength+= finalDistances.get(j);
            System.out.println("Tree length is: "+treeLength);
        }

        //fail safe
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Shit broke!");
        }
    }

}
```

The input is just a txt file formated like:

```
0
    25    244
   108    275
   140    273
   159    313
   219    199
   254    392
   369    171
   518    271
   538    250
   568    253
   603    307
   613    196
   638    314

1
    24    187
    43    182
    65    331
   155    369
   182    222
   186    426
   224    395
   233     72
   240    128
   250    101
   269    251
   371     73
   409    301
   444     40
   451    262
   464    337
   517    393
   569    171
   586    384
   599    221
   601    145
   611    209
   616    330
   629    324
   644    254
   646    316
   675    237
   684    327
   695    439
   696    288
```

The first line is the number of nodes and edges. A number by itself on a line is a Node and the numbers after are edges with weights. My Node class just has a int value, arraylist of edges, and a distance from source. My Edge class has a int value, and int weight.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {
    int value;
    ArrayList<Edge> edges;
    boolean seen;
    int distance;
    public Node(int value) {
        edges = new ArrayList<>();
        this.value = value;
        seen = false;
    }
    public void add (Edge edge) {
        edges.add(edge);
    }
    @Override
    //debugging use
    public String toString() {
        String listOfEdges= "";
        //for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        //  listOfEdges = listOfEdges + " ," + Integer.toString(edges.get(i).end);
        //}
        return "Node: "+Integer.toString(value); //+" Edges: "+listOfEdges;
    }
}
```

```
public class Edge {
    int end;
    int weight;
    public Edge(int end, int weight) {
        this.end = end;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    @Override
    //debugging use
    public String toString() {
        return "Edge: "+end+" Weight: "+weight;
    }
}
```

It seems to be after a point running the algorithm, some vertices remain infinity, and others negative infinity. I'm using two arrays: first is the heap that stores the Nodes, and second is to store the indexes of Nodes in the heap. The full class is below:

```
    private int capacity;
    private int currentSize;
    private Node[] heap;
    private int[] locations;
    //private HashMap<Integer, Integer> locations = new HashMap<>();

    public MinHeap(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        heap = new Node[capacity];
        locations = new int[capacity];
        //heap[0] = new Node(-1);
        //heap[0].distance = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        currentSize = 0;
    }
    private int getParent(int index) {
        return (index-1)/2;
    }
    private int getLeftChild(int index) {
        return index*2+1;
    }
    private int getRightChild(int index) {
        return index*2+2;
    }
    private void swap(int a, int b) {
        Node temp = heap[a];
        heap[a] = heap[b];
        heap[b] = temp;
        //maybe bug


    }
    Node extractMin() {
        Node min = heap[0];
        Node last = heap[currentSize-1];
        swap (0,currentSize-1);
        locations[last.value] = 0;
        locations[min.value] = -1;
        currentSize--;
        heapifyDown(0);
        System.out.println("heap size: "+currentSize);
        return min;
    }
    void heapifyDown(int index) {
        int currentIndex = index;
        int leftIndex = getLeftChild(currentIndex);
        int rightIndex = getRightChild(currentIndex);
        if (leftIndex < currentSize && heap[currentIndex].distance > heap[leftIndex].distance) {
            currentIndex = leftIndex;
        }
        if (rightIndex < currentSize && heap[currentIndex].distance > heap[rightIndex].distance) {
            currentIndex = rightIndex;
        }
        if (currentIndex != index) {
            Node newTop = heap[currentIndex];
            Node oldTop = heap[index];

            locations[newTop.value] = index;
            locations[oldTop.value] = currentIndex;
            swap(index,currentIndex);
            heapifyDown(currentIndex);
        }
    }
    void heapifyUp(int index) {
        int parentIndex = getParent(index);
        int currentIndex = index;
        Node currentNode = heap[currentIndex];
        Node parentNode = heap[parentIndex];
        while (currentIndex > 0 && heap[parentIndex].distance > heap[currentIndex].distance) {
            System.out.println("Swapped: "+heap[getParent(currentIndex)].toString()+" That has a distance of: "+heap[getParent(currentIndex)].distance+ " With: "+heap[currentIndex]+" Which has a distance of: "+heap[currentIndex].distance);
            swap(parentIndex,currentIndex);
            locations[currentNode.value] = parentIndex;
            locations[parentNode.value] = currentIndex;
            currentIndex = parentIndex;
            parentIndex = getParent(parentIndex);

            System.out.println("min: "+heap[0].toString());
        }
    }
    public void decreaseKey(Node node, int distance) {
        int location = locations[node.value];
        heap[location].distance = distance;
        heapifyUp(location);
    }
    public void insert(Node node) {
        //currentSize++;
        int index = currentSize;
        heap[currentSize] = node;
        locations[node.value] = currentSize;
        currentSize++;
        heapifyUp(index);
    }
    public boolean contains(int node) {
        return locations[node] != 0 && locations[node] != -1;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return currentSize==0;
    }
    public Node getNode(Node node) {
        return heap[locations[node.value]];
    }
    public Node getNode(int nodeValue) {
        return heap[locations[nodeValue]];
    }
    public void updateNode(Node node) {
        heap[locations[node.value]] = node;
    }
    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(heap[i].toString());
        }
    }
    public Node peek() {
        return heap[0];
    }
    public int size() {
        return currentSize;
    }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain the input file? For example what is the meaning of the first 3 numbers? 0
    25    244

Comment: 0 is the first node, node 25 is connected to 0 with a weight of 244

Comment: Do you have the code and input file uploaded on like github to clone and debug?

Comment: Sure here you go: [Github](https://github.com/SafestSpace/Algorithms-Dijkstra-Implementation)